# onSubmit using Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to follow a course that uses Formik but I keep getting a compile error when defining the `onSubmit` method. The snippet is the following:

```
const onSubmit = (values, actions) => {
  props.logIn(values.username, values.password);
  setSubmitted(true);
};
```

According to the documentation listed [here](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik) there should be braces at the beggining of `(values, actions)` but I keep getting the error `setSubmitted is not defined`

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Quick guess, but in example it initializes function within render. How do you use yours within that context?  If it is `onSubmit={onSubmit}` try adding another arrow function to declaration: `const onSubmit = (values, actions) => () => {`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited the question since the error was not getting `setSubmitted` because is undefined. Do you know if I should I import something?

Comment: In example it is used from `actions`. `actions.setSubmitting(true)`, try that.

Comment: Super! I am glad.